# Docker prom/Prometheus container exits

Tags: docker, containers, prometheus, nginx-config

when i run this command it creates the docker container but shows in exit status
and i am not able to get it started

my goal is to be able to replace prometheus.yml file with a custom prometheus.yml to monitor nginx running at http://localhost:70/nginx_status

```
   docker run -it -d --name prometheus3 -p 9090:9090 -v 
    /opt/docker/prometheus:/etc/prometheus prom/prometheus - 
    config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

here is my prometheus.yml file

```
     scrape_configs: 
     - job_name: 'prometheus' 

     scrape_interval: 5s 
     scrape_timeout: 5s 

     static_configs: 
       - targets: ['localhost: 9090'] 

       - job_name: 'node' 
     static_configs: 
     - targets: ['localhost: 70/nginx_status']
```

Comment: docker log prometheus3 shows nothing

Comment: There are a couple of extra spaces in this that I wouldn't expect (before `config.file`; after `localhost:`); can you double-check that the post matches what you have on disk?

Comment: You have multiple static configs sections. In yml that typically overwrites the first config.

Comment: @bMitch I am not able to get to editing the prometheus.yml file on  the host cause it says that the container has exited

Comment: @David yes there seems to be some kind of space issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see the logs of the stopped container by running:

`docker logs prometheus3`

Anyway, there are (at least) two issues with your configuration:

1. The prometheus.yml file is invalid so the prometheus process immediately exits.
   The `scrape_interval` and `scrape_timeout` need to be in a `global` section and the indentation was off. See below for an example of a correctly formatted yml file.

   2.) You can't just scrape the `/nginx_status` endpoint but need to use a nginx exporter which extracts the metrics for you. Then the Prometheus server will scrape the nginx_exporter to retrieve the metrics. You can find a list of exporters [here](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exporters.md#http) and pick one that suits you.
   Once you have the exporter running, you need to point Prometheus to the address of the exporter so it can be scraped.

Working prometheus.yml :

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s 
  scrape_timeout: 5s 

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'node' 
    static_configs: 
    - targets: ['<< host name and port of nginx exporter >>']
```